# Rails Watir: Wait for 5 seconds before reading element text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, sleep, watir

I have a website that has a <h1> element.

This element has value x as innerhtml at page load and value y after z seconds.

I don't know what the values of x and y are, because they change frequently. z could be anywhere between 0 to 5. I can't use wait_until or wait_while because of this. So this really wouldn't work, because I don't know what to wait for.

```
Watir::Wait.until(5) {
  element.text == "abracadabra"
}
```

So really I need to wait for 5 seconds and then check the text of the element. Does Watir has some kind of timout function I can use? Like the javascript `setTimeout()`?

Comment: you are wring a test to see if there is an element on the screen?

Comment: Do you know that it would change such that you get the original value and wait for the value not to be that?

Comment: @Rajagopalan: No The element is always on screen. I want the value after it has changed. And the change can occur immediately or within 5 seconds. If the change occurs immediately it the same as if it was never changed. Watir gives me the changed value even if I request it asap.

Comment: @titusfortner That would be possible in most cases, but if the change happens too quickly then I miss the original value completely. Watir gives me the changed value the first time I ask for it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how often you need to do this as to whether you should prefer just doing a hard coded sleep or something more dynamic.

This is another option:

```
browser.goto my_dynamic_page
dynamic_text_element = browser.h1(locator_opt)
final_text = updated_text(dynamic_text_element)

def updated_text(element)
  original_text = element.text
  begin
    element.wait_until(timeout: 5) { |e| e.text != original_text }
  rescue Watir::Wait::TimeoutError
  end
  element.text
end
```

Comment: This would work in most cases except for when the change happens very quickly. In that case I will miss the original text completely. The first time I request the value it would already be the changed value.

Comment: That's what the timeout: 5  is for. If it has changed before the first check, it acts just like a sleep 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ruby's `sleep` method:

```
sleep(num_secs)
```

It takes integer or float values.

Documentation is here: https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sleep

Comment: I don't like it, but I guess it's my only option right now.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Hardcoded waits in UI automation are usually not a good advice.
Thanks for accepting and upvoting the answer.